# Why does on demand Incremental Static Regeneration only works when passing an specific route as argument in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I've seen the documentations, the oficial videos from Vercel and sometimes, on the revalidate API they call `res.unstable_revalidate('/')` with just a slah (presumably to revalidate the whole application) and sometimes they call with it passing a specific page (to revalidate only that page).

In my tests passing just slash is not working and I have no idea why. How could I debug this?

Below I have a page which prints a new Date() and only gets updated when I call one of two buttons 'revalidate' or 'revalidate specific'. Only 'revalidate specific works'

api/revalidate.ts

```
export default async function handler(req: any, res: any): Promise<any> {
  // Check for secret to confirm this is a valid request
  //   if (req.query.secret !== process.env.MY_SECRET_TOKEN) {
  //     return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' });
  //   }

  const { page } = req.body;

  if (page && !page.match(/^\/.*$/)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid URL' });
  }

  try {
    if (page) {
      console.info(`[Next.js] Revalidating ${page}`);
      await res.unstable_revalidate(page);
    } else {
      console.info('[Next.js] Revalidating /');
      await res.unstable_revalidate('/');
    }
    return res.json({ revalidated: true });
  } catch (err) {
    // If there was an error, Next.js will continue
    // to show the last successfully generated page
    return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating');
  }
}
```

src/pages/myPage.tsx

```
/* eslint-disable react/button-has-type */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types */
export function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      time: new Date().toISOString(),
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}

export default function Home({ time }: { time: any }) {
  function revalidate() {
    fetch('api/revalidate');
  }

  function revalidateSpecific() {
    fetch('api/revalidate', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ page: '/myPage' }),
    });
  }

  return (
    <h1>
      <div>{time}</div>
      <div>
        <button
          style={{ border: '1px solid black', backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
          onClick={() => revalidate()}
        >
          Revalidate
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          style={{ border: '1px solid black', backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
          onClick={() => revalidateSpecific()}
        >
          Revalidate specific page
        </button>
      </div>
    </h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: `res.unstable_revalidate('/')` doesn't revalidate the whole app, it revalidates that specific `/` path. You always have to be specific on the path you want to revalidate, there is no "revalidate all paths" option.

Comment: @juliomalves yeah, that's why got it from reading more and testing too, but I think it should've been clearer on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is deployed on Vercel you can call a unique API URL (GET) that'll rebuild the site.
https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/deploy-hooks#creating-a-deploy-hook